# How to update shown text in list when item changed with JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, html-select

I have a list (`<select>`), and I programmatically change the text of one of the items. 
When I open the list, I can see that the item has changed, although the list still shows old text.

```
<select id="myList">
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3">Item 3</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Change" onclick="changeText();">

function changeText()
{ 
    $("#myList option:selected").text("new Item Text");
}
```

I.e: I choose "Item 2", then press the button "Change". Now the list has 3 elements ("Item 1", "new Item Text" and "Item 3"), but it still shows "Item 2". The only way I've found to update it is select another element and then changed one, although it's not feasible because connections to DB...

What am I doing wrong or what could I do to solve this?

Comment: are you using some plugin to style the `select` element ? because your current element works fine for normal `select` elements : [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/z84ck1bc/)

Comment: yes, there are some js files and css, I inherited this code :( jquery-1.9.1.min.js --- jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css --- jqm-icon-pack-2.0-original.css --- jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js. I am newbie, and I was glad to have the styles already done, but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you are using the jquery mobile which applies its own styling and shows the selected value in another element.

You need to trigger the `change` event on the `select` so that it gets picked by the jquery-mobile and updates the relevant display field.

```
$("#myList option:selected").text("new Item Text").trigger('change');
```

Demo with jquery mobile: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/z84ck1bc/1/

---

**Update** thanks to @Omar's comment

The correct thing to do is to call the [`refresh` method](http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh) on the selectmenu.

```
$("#myList option:selected").text("new Item Text");
$('#myList').selectmenu('refresh');
```

Comment: It's not the solution I'd like to implement, because when the selection changes makes queries to the DB, but as I need it to work  as soon as posible, I'll do it. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @TheG the answer is a _fix_, the correct way is refreshing selectmenu whenever you add/remove elements or do any other changes. `$("#myList").selectmenu("refresh")` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/z84ck1bc/2/

Answer (score -1):

I checked it is working fine with below jquery version:

jquery-1.9.1.js

simply i am using below code:

```
<select id="myList">
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3">Item 3</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Change" onclick="changeText();">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeText() {
        $("#myList option:selected").text("new Item Text");
    };
</script>
```